# How to run remote ssh command in sbt script?

Tags: sbt

I want to deploy and automatically run a script on a remote machine.

However, I don't know how I can issue a remote command.

I've tried several things and plugins but none of that stuff seems to work.

Is there a way to do it?

```
val deployAndRunTask = TaskKey[Unit]("deploy-run", "Deploy and run application.")

deployAndRunTask := {

  // Deploy .jar file
  val _ = deployTask.value

  println("Running the script ..")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example, which you can save in `test.sbt` in the top level directory of your SBT project. The `shellRun` method runs an arbitrary command. I use `shellRun` to run `ssh`, connect to the local machine, and list the files in my home directory.

```
import scala.sys.process.Process

val deployAndRunTask = TaskKey[Unit]("deploy-and-run-task", "Short example")

deployAndRunTask := {
  def shellRun(command: String*) = Process(command.toSeq).!!.trim

  val result = shellRun("/usr/bin/ssh", "localhost", "ls")
  println(result)
}
```

Run it by typing:

```
sbt deployAndRunTask
```